# How do I tell Titanium to choose an app icon based on screen density?

Tags: android, titanium

I'm starting to think that Titanium has no real support for app icons for different screen densities. It's possible to setup the directory structure, but the tiapp.xml configuration wizard **requires** a single icon.

Here is my directory structure:

```
platform
    /android
        /res
            /drawable
                appicon.png
            /drawable-hdpi
                appicon
            ... etc, for mdpi, ldpi, and xhdpi
Resources
    /android
        /images
            ... Folders containing my splash screens (res-long-land-hdpi, res-long-land-ldpi, etc)
        appicon.png
    /ui
    app.js
```

Currently, Titanium uses `Resources/android/appicon.png` as the app icon. How can I tell it to choose the app icon at runtime from `platform/android/res`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Titanium does support this.

Create the directory structure like I did above, and leave a *fake* `appicon.png` in `Resources/android/`. Titanium will, when compiling the project, ignore `Resources/android/appicon.png` and correctly use the ones in `platform/android`.